# Adobe analytics with vue js adding external script

Tags: vue.js, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

Im struggling to add adobe analytics external scripts to my Vue js project. The client uses Adobe  analytics and im battling to add it to the project without the project complaining.

The external adobe script looks like the following:

```
//assets.adobedtm.com/file.min.js with async
```

Then it is required that you end it by adding the following just before the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>
```

When the project starts it complains in console that $ is not defined because it is defined in webpack when i start the project and im guessing its not finding the alias.

This is the error:

```
VM29714:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Then further down it complains that it doesnt know what _satellite is:

```
login:54 Uncaught ReferenceError: _satellite is not defined
```

I just need the scripts and satellite close to be added to the project, the rest will work once these are added.

Ive tried added the scripts by injecting them into the head tag on runtime but that also doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing Adobe DTM, you **cannot** inject the header script dynamically. It must be placed directly on the page **without** async or deferred attributes.

If you are implementing Adobe Launch, you can inject the header script dynamically and asynchronously. And if you do this, you do **not** include the footer (`_satellite.pageBottom()`) code.

Your script example isn't explicit, but the `.min` portion implies you are using Adobe Launch.

`VM29714:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

This is not directly related to either Adobe DTM or Launch. You may possibly have some other script or code block deployed inside the DTM or Launch interface that references `$`, but that's a separate issue to work out. Yes, it may be coming from a DTM or Launch script according to the js console, but keep in mind that DTM/Launch is a tag manager. It hosts and deploys other tags/scripts. So you need to do some digging to see which tag/script from which Rule references it. Start by looking at the stack trace to find out where it's coming from.